# How do I measure how long operations take on an Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino

I'm writing code that requires me to have certain code run at exact times (Like a loop taking 8ms long) on an Arduino Mega. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate this by finding out how long it takes for a Mega to make one calculation and multiplying it by the # of calculations in a certain block of code. Is this the correct way of approaching this problem? How do I even count how many calculations are going on?

Comment: Very bad approach using CPU timing for such long loops. Use a timer.

Comment: I'm mainly trying to figure out how to make sure my loop is a specific length. Do I just use a timer and keep messing with the code till I like it? Or is there a more exact way to do that?

Comment: What have you researched yourself? Why do the ways you can find on the web net work? Did you do **any** reseach yourself? What is your actual problem? - too broad, this is no consulting site.

Comment: I'm only asking how to make a block of code take a certain amount of time. I have done research, and have only found information regarding delays. And that's not what I want. I want to write a loop of code and make sure it takes 8ms to execute. It isn't that broad.

Comment: So in your research you haven't found useful to use `timed interrupts` or functions like `millis()` or `micros()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to implement a timer is by using `millis()` in your `loop()` function and comparing it against the last time your code ran, something like this:

```
long loopTime = 0;
loop()
{
    if (millis() - loopTime >= 8)
    {
        // Do the stuff here that you want to happen every 8ms
        // ...
        //

        // Keep track of the last time this code ran, so we'll run it
        // again 8 ms from now
        loopTime = millis()
    }

    // Do other stuff here
}
```

Note that this will not be precise, because the `millis()` function doesn't guarantee an exact figure.  If you require absolute precision you'd need to use some sort of external hardware timer to generate an interrupt every 8 ms.  Interrupt programming gets a bit more complex, but the timing loop technique shown above should work for most things that don't require absolute precision.